# Download Image from url is sometimes returning null image

Tags: android

I am using the following code to download a bitmap from a url,:

```
myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);


HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                    .openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
Bitmap bmpTemp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

but sometimes, I mean once in a hundred times, the bitmap is null! any body knows what might be the problem,

Thanks

Comment: 这里有好的方法
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085916/android-download-of-bitmap-returns-null-sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the url connection. It has a fix that uses a FlushedInputStream decorator function for it.
here is the code for it:

```
 /*
     * An InputStream that skips the exact number of bytes provided, unless it reaches EOF.
     */
    public static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

        public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
            super(inputStream);
        }
        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
            while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                    int b = read();
                    if (b < 0) {
                        break;  // we reached EOF
                    } else {
                        bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                    }
                }
                totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
            }
            return totalBytesSkipped;
        }
    }
```

the usage is:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! do you an official documentation to this bug to send to our client, he will not be convinced that it was an android bug till he sees an official documentation, Thanks again

Comment: Thanksss ! that was a lot of help