# Android Download of bitmap returns null sometimes

Tags: android

I am using the code below in asyn task to download a bitmap to be added to my custom class. however sometimes it return nulls with no IOException or any exception. i am not very sure what can be done

```
    public  Bitmap downloadFile(String fileUrl){
    URL myFileUrl =null;          
    try {
        myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        //conn.setReadTimeout(500000000);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
           BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o);
        is.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        int scale = 1;
        int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE=400;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }
        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        //conn.setReadTimeout(500000000);
        conn.connect();
        is  =  conn.getInputStream();
       Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
       if (b==null)
           Log.e(Config.log_id, " Download image failed");
    return b;

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Config.log_id, " Download image failed"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this as well when using unbuffered variants of
stream readers when getting from urls.

The simple solution that worked for me was to use a BufferedHttpEntity to get the image data.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;

public static Bitmap decodeFromUrl(HttpClient client, URL url, Config bitmapCOnfig)
    {
        HttpResponse response=null;
        Bitmap b=null;
        InputStream instream=null;

        BitmapFactory.Options decodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        decodeOptions.inPreferredConfig = bitmapCOnfig;
        try
        {
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
            response = client.execute(request);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
            {
                MyLogger.w("Bad response on " + url.toString());
                MyLogger.w ("http response: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
                return null;
            }
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
            instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream, null, decodeOptions);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyLogger.e("error decoding bitmap from:" + url, ex);
            if (response != null)
            {
                MyLogger.e("http status: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (instream != null)
            {
                try {
                    instream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    MyLogger.e("error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, decodeOptions);  

This code doesnt allow BufferedReader class. Are you sure you its for android

Comment: hi may i know what is inPreferredConfig

Comment: Basically just what color depth you want it decoded as. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html BitmapConfig.ARGB_888 is most common...but heavy. BitmapConfig.RGB_565 is good compromise

Comment: just tried that method. however it still result in same error

 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     Bitmap a1= decodeFromUrl(httpclient,new URL(Config.address+"/images/members/thumbnail/"+json_data.getString("memberid")+json_data.getString("photo")));
  is inside my doinbackground asyntask. I gave the config null and called the method.

Result in same error. some of them is still null

Comment: And if you do pass a BitmapConfig.ARGB_888 ? Also, if youre running pre 2.2, you might have a look at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066 see comment #12 for another possible fix.  The code I provided resolved the same issues for me.

Comment: You can also try just wrapping the inputstream in your original code with BufferedInputStream as in: BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

Comment: May i know why BufferedHttpEntity  worked while inputstream is not working?

Comment: hi, just tried
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); using my old code and it doesn't work :(. failed for some image

Comment: I havent a clue why. Just glad that BufferedHttpEntity approach works.

Comment: hey man thx. at least you helped me. I've previosuly asked the same qn but people seems unable to solve it